Loading 64 bit mode from C code in 32 bit mode
I tried to use in C "extern void (function_name)" then call that function in my C code. It got to the assembly code that i used the extern on. Problem was it setted up 64 bit mode but when it needed to jump to the long mode it failed. All code is compiled right and other stuff is all correct, only problem is with the jmp
//Problem: jmp 0x08:init_lm

extern void _init_load_lm(void);

void main(void) 
{
    _init_load_lm();
    *(char*)0xb8000 = 'Q';
    for(;;);
}

// Assembly code:

bits 32

global _init_load_lm

_init_load_lm:    
    ;Enable PAE
    mov eax, cr4                 
    or eax, 1 << 5               
    mov cr4, eax

    ;# Optional : Enable global-page mechanism by setting CR0.PGE bit to 1
    mov eax, cr4                 
    or eax, 1 << 7               
    mov cr4, eax

    ;Load CR3 with PML4 base address
    ;NB: in some examples online, the address is not offseted as it seems to
    ;be in the proc datasheet (if you were wondering about this strange thing).
    mov eax, 0x1000
    mov cr3, eax

    ;Set LME bit in EFER register (address 0xC0000080)
    mov ecx, 0xC0000080     ;operand of 'rdmsr' and 'wrmsr'
    rdmsr                   ;read before pr ne pas écraser le contenu
    or eax, 1 << 8          ;eax : operand de wrmsr
    wrmsr

    ;Enable paging by setting CR0.PG bit to 1
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, (1 << 31)
    mov cr0, eax

    ;Load 64-bit GDT
    lgdt [gdt64_descriptor]

    ;Jump to code segment in 64-bit GDT
    jmp 0x8:init_lm

bits 64

init_lm
    mov ax, 0x10
    mov fs, ax          ;other segments are ignored
    mov gs, ax

    mov rbp, 0x90000    ;set up stack
    mov rsp, rbp

    mov al, 'E'
    mov ah, 0x0f
    mov [0xb8000], ax

    ret                 ; return back to c code where it should be called from

bits 32
GDT64
;null;
    dq 0x0

;code
    dd 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 0b10011000   
    db 0b00100000
    db 0x0

;data
    dd 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 0b10010000   
    db 0b00000000
    db 0x0

gdt64_descriptor:
    dw $ - GDT64 - 1        ;16-bit size
    dd GDT64                ;32-bit start address


// Edit: Page table

[bits 32]
build_page_tables:
    ;PML4 starts at 0x1000
    ;il faut laisser la place pour tte la page PML4/PDP/PD ie. 0x1000

    ;PML4 @ 0x1000
    mov eax, 0x2000         ;PDP base address            
    or eax, 0b11            ;P and R/W bits
    mov ebx, 0x1000         ;MPL4 base address
    mov [ebx], eax

    ;PDP @ 0x2000; maps 64Go
    mov eax, 0x3000         ;PD base address
    mov ebx, 0x2000         ;PDP physical address   
    mov ecx, 64             ;64 PDP

    build_PDP:
        or eax, 0b11    
        mov [ebx], eax
        add ebx, 0x8
        add eax, 0x1000     ;next PD page base address
        loop build_PDP

    ;PD @ 0x3000 (ends at 0x4000, fits below 0x7c00)
    ; 1 entry maps a 2MB page, the 1st starts at 0x0
    mov eax, 0x0            ;1st page physical base address     
    mov ebx, 0x3000         ;PD physical base address
    mov ecx, 512                        

    build_PD:
        or eax, 0b10000011      ;P + R/W + PS (bit for 2MB page)
        mov [ebx], eax
        add ebx, 0x8
        add eax, 0x200000       ;next 2MB physical page
        loop build_PD

    ;(tables end at 0x4000 => fits before Bios boot sector at 0x7c00)
    ret



The Limit & Base field of GDT code and data should not be 0x0

Follow this page

Could i have a example what to put for the 0x0, because currently i have no idea what to do also it cannot be a random number. Thank you. Should i remove it? '0x0'

The C language is not architecture specific.  It has no standard facility for choosing or querying architecture or instruction set details.  When you link objects built from different sources, it is on you to ensure that they are compatible, with being built for the same instruction set being an important consideration (albeit one rarely requiring special attention).  If you want an x86 program then build all sources for that architecture.  That may take special compiler flags if x86 is not the build machine's native architecture.

You have not shown how you set up page tables (if at all). This is not a [mcve]. Also, learn to use a debugger.
